# How to create a slideshow timer and add functioning tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I've tried various different things to implement this but nothing seems to work for me i am trying to make the current progress bar have functionality e.g goes according to when each slide changes, and also add tabs that will allow a user to jump to a slide on click.

**[Demo Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/yr7tkzab/show/)**

**Html**

```
<div class="omega_player">
    <ul class="omega_slides">
        <li>SLIDE 1</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
        <li>SLIDE 3</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="omega_controls">
        <div class="omega_timer"><div class="progress"></div></div>
        <div class="omega_set">
            <a onclick="return false" class="control_prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
            <a onclick="return false" class="control_play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
            <a onclick="return false" class="control_pause"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></a>
            <a onclick="return false" class="control_next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 8000);

    var slideCount = $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('.omega_player').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li:last-child').prependTo('.omega_player>.omega_slides');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li:last-child').prependTo('.omega_player>.omega_slides');
            $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li:first-child').appendTo('.omega_player>.omega_slides');
            $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_prev').click(function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play').show();
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause').hide();
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_next').click(function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play').show();
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause').hide();
        moveRight();
    });

    $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play').click(function () {
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play').hide();
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause').show();
        moveRight();
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            moveRight();
        }, 8000);
    });

    $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause').click(function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play').show();
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause').hide()
    });

    return timer;

});
```

**CSS**

```
.omega_player {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 950px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.omega_player>.omega_slides {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 450px;
list-style: none;
}
.omega_player>.omega_slides>li {
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 950px;
height: 450px;
background: #ccc;
text-align: center;
line-height: 300px;
}

.omega_player>.omega_controls {
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 50px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #333;
background: rgba(51,51,51,.8);
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
width: 100%;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set {
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_prev,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_next {
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
z-index: 999;
display: block;
padding: 4% 3%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
background: #2a2a2a;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 18px;
opacity: 0.8;
cursor: pointer;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_prev:hover,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_next:hover {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_prev {
border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_play,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_pause {
background-color: green;
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_play {
display: none!important;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>a {
color: #FFF;
color: rgba(250,250,250,.95);
font-size: 20px;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>:hover {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
color: #FFF;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_prev,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_next,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause {
font-size: 45px;
line-height: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
transition: .1s ease-in-out;
border: 1px solid #FFF;
border-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.65);
border-top: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
float: left;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause {
border:0;
font-size: 25px;
line-height: 48px;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play {
display:none;
}

.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_timer {
background: #333;
background: rgba(51,51,51,.9);
height: 4px;
top: -4px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_timer>.progress {
height: 4px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #EB0000;
background: rgba(235, 0, 0, 0.86);
position: absolute;
width: 60%;
z-index: 999;
}

html,
body {margin:0;padding:0;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px;}
```

Hope you can help thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically people here will expect code along with fiddle since fiddle link may fail anytime and in that case there is no point of this question where users find it useful. so you need to assist your fiddle with code or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[Code with 4 Slides](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yr7tkzab/6/)** and **[Full Screen DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yr7tkzab/6/embedded/result/)**
>
> **[Code with 8 Slides](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yr7tkzab/5/)** and **[Full Screen DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yr7tkzab/5/embedded/result/)**

Here you go. I have just written a function which will calculate `progressbar`'s width based on number of `elements` present and `active slide`. Below is how the `function` looks like:

```
function progress(){
    var activeElement=$('li:nth-child(2)').attr('data-slide');
    //get the activeElement which will be always as 2nd child as per your code
    var width=(increment*activeElement)+'%';
    //increment variable will be based on `100/numberofslidespresent`
    //each li should have a data-* property, say data-slide here, which will actually
    //contain number in incremental order. Now multiply increment and activeElement
    //and add % so that it will become something like 25%, 50% everytime.
    $('.progress').animate({
         'width':width //animate width of progressbar
    },300);
}
```

Here is the complete code:

**Html**

```
<div class="omega_player">
    <ul class="omega_slides">
        <li data-slide="1">SLIDE 1</li>
        <li data-slide="2" style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
        <li data-slide="3">SLIDE 3</li>
        <li data-slide="4" style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
        <!--extra property added to each li which data-slide with incremental number-->
    </ul>
    <ul class="omega_controls">
        <div class="omega_timer"><div class="progress"></div></div>
        <div class="omega_set">
            <a onclick="return false" class="control_prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
            <a onclick="return false" class="control_play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
            <a onclick="return false" class="control_pause"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></a>
            <a onclick="return false" class="control_next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var increment; // a global variable
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 8000);
    var slideCount = $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li').length;
    increment=100/slideCount; //get how much to increment parts should be
    var slideWidth = $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
    $('.omega_player').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li:last-child').prependTo('.omega_player>.omega_slides');
    progress();//call this function once prepended on page load

    function moveLeft() {
        $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li:last-child').prependTo('.omega_player>.omega_slides').addClass('active');
            progress(); //after prepending call it once again
            $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {

        $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li').removeClass('active')
        $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li:first-child').appendTo('.omega_player>.omega_slides');
            progress(); //after appending call it once again
            $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').css('left', '');
        });

    };

   //Your other functions here remains as it is so I haven't attached them   
});  

function progress(){
    var activeElement=$('li:nth-child(2)').attr('data-slide');
    var width=(increment*activeElement)+'%';
    $('.progress').animate({
         'width':width
    },300);
}
```

**CSS**

> On CSS part I just changed width mentioned for `progressbar` from 60% to
>   0%

Comment: Yeah that exactly what I was looking for although when I click on the tabs it doesn't seem to work correctly, also once implemented with my code it seems to break! [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oc5bp0u6/4/show/)

Comment: @RRAWebteam Your tabs doesn't even work?? was it working previously?

Comment: I don't think I posted the correct link prior, and yeah but it didn't correspond with the timer so i removed the code and now I've lost it. [NEW JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oc5bp0u6/4/show/)

Comment: Can you just show working link with tab so that I will update my answer accordingly!

Comment: The link to the original JSFiddle? Also I no longer have the code for the tabs I've deleted because it wasn't working.]

Comment: So now is this ok you need any fix and if you need any fix to which link I need to apply fix?

Comment: @RRAWebteam If you see the html I've show in answer I've added an extra attribute to each `li` which is data-slide and you are missing that attribute in the link provided by you in the first comment. Here is the same **[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/oc5bp0u6/5/)** for you.. Check and let me know...

Comment: I need a fix for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oc5bp0u6/4/show/), I have added tabs and I'm trying to let users click on a tab to advance the slide; as well as the timer.

Comment: Could you please help me finish this off please!

Comment: yea I am trying on that.. Actually the way you are animating the slides is kind of difficult to understand.. will see how I can help on that!

Comment: Your welcome to change, if it helps any as well as giving a smoother transition? And thanks alot!